# Save files with ActionScript in Flash Builder is possible?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I've read that it is not possible to save files using Flash CS5.

Later I've read that it is possible using Adobe Flex.

Now, what about using Flash Builder?

**--update**

I'm talking about save data files at runtime, such as user usage data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Builder and Flash CS5 both generate SWFs, as do other 3rd party products.  All SWFs will have the same capabilities regardless of how they were generated.  Anything Flash Builder can do Flash CS5 can also do.

Flex is the framework Flash Builder (formerly Flex Builder) uses.  The framework provides a lot of useful functionality, but it's all done in ActionScript itself so it doesn't do anything that cannot be done with CS5 (although with a lot of work).

A web-hosted swf can save files to the local computer as long as the user has allowed it.  The user specifically has to browser to the save location and then the runtime can write out a file.  It can also save data to the Local Shared Object which is basically like a cookie but has more capacity and can save typed data.

An Adobe AIR application can save any local file.  Both Flash Builder and Flash CS5 can generate AIR applications, which have to be installed locally.

Comment: @Tom so yes if you are targeting Flash Player 9 or below then Local Shared Object is the only way if you are not using a server. If you target Flash Player 10 then you have the ability to save a file to their local as well (but it must be initiated by the user).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to save files in both Flash CS5 and Adobe Flash Builder.  If you are asking about .as files specifically... I know Flash Builder can handle them.